# How do I determine if given set is a subspace of the specified vector space (answer provided)?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine (with proof) if given set is a subspace of the specified vector space.

The set of vectors $$ \begin{pmatrix} a+3b-c  \\  2b-4c \\ 5a +  6c\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ in $\Bbb R^4$

My answer is:
The column space of an $m \times n$ matrix is a subspace of $\Bbb R^m$. $A$ is a $4 \times 3$ matrix, and the set is the column space of $A$, therefore the set is a subspace of $\Bbb R^4$.

Is that correct and sufficient enough? Thank you

Comment: I think what you need to prove is that, when $a,b,c$ run over all triplets of reals, the set you get is closed under sums and under multiplication by scalars.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is
 $$ \begin{pmatrix} a+3b-c  \\  2b-4c \\ 5a +  6c\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}= a\begin{pmatrix} 1  \\  0\\ 5\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+b \begin{pmatrix} 3  \\  2 \\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+c \begin{pmatrix} -1  \\  -4 \\   6\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=a{\bf{u}}+b{\bf{v}}+c{\bf{w}}$$ 
so the given set is spaned by $\bf{u},\bf{v}$ and $\bf{w}$ so it's a subspace.

Comment: I appreciate you for showing another way, but could you tell me if my answer is correct and sufficient enough? Thank you

Comment: What's the matrix $A$ you tell about? can you explicit it?

Answer (score 0):

It is correct.

If you explicate the matrix $A$ you are talking about, then I would argue this is certainly enough (provided you are allowed to use that the column space is a subspace).

If you have to do it otherwise, you can always just check the two conditions for being a subspace, viz closure under addition and scalar multiplication.